# ASP.net Ajax Tab Container - Populating data based on tab clicked

Tags: asp.net-ajax

i implemented ajax tab conatiner control in my asp.net c# web application.

Here, i have four tabs with same user control embedded in each of the tab.

Now , i need to populate the user control in each tab with different data based on the tab clicked.

How do i identify which tab is clicked ?

suppose if i click on tab1 the user control should call one data access function to fetch data similarly for other tabs..

Any sugesstions on the above is highly appreciated

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please help on above..i tried with Activetabindexchanged() method..but unable to succeed..is there any other approach to accomplish this

Comment: Dear All , I have found solution for the above problem . We have a property called ActiveTabIndex which indicates current tab or tab pressed. So, what i have done is declared a public method in the user ontrol for binding data and passing ActiveTabIndex as parameter to it.So ,Based on tab clicked it populates data. The event used here is Server side event ActiveTabIndexChanged which causes a post back. So , make sure you have kept Ajax tab Container under Update Panel and also dont forget AutoPostBack=true..That's it..